# JQuery code not working on website but is workingon codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to use this [code](https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/input-number-group.html) for custom number input. Copied it to codepen and it works there too, but when copying it to my site its not working anymore. Theres no console errors. Im linking the same jquery as in the codepen (2.1.3). Console returns `ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}` for $.

Heres the code on my site, using the same 2.1.3 jQuery

```js
$('.input-number-increment').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val + 1);
});

$('.input-number-decrement').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val - 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6 class="text-center">Unit(s)</h6>
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
  </div>
  <input class="input-number" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="1000">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "_not working_", as  the code in the question seems to "work" ..?

Comment: not working as in the the increment and decrement buttons are not doing anything on my site

Comment: No? That doesn't seem to be true, the code on the page you've linked works exactly the same way as the snippet in the question. Maybe you have a caching problem, empty the browser cache, and re-try.

Comment: Are you link jQuery before your script?

Comment: That is the weird part, i have the code exactly the same on my site on an empty index, yet its not doing anything. I have tried on different devices.

Comment: But that page is not linked in the question ... There's nothing here with which we could reproduce your issue. Make sure the jQuery library and all the involved HTML elements are fully loaded and parsed before running the script.